# How to change font family only numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On whole my website there are many places that use numbers. because my font doesn't good to numbers.I would like to change font them to what I wanted.

now similar questions asked before but I not find a good answer to do this.
some answers suggests to use jquery/javascript function. but I think using jquery/javascript function make lazy my webpages.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Do you want to change the font of `<input type="number" />` or the numbers shown on the page?

Comment: yes, I want this

Comment: @Tushar gave you two options, you can't really answer with `yes, I want this`

Answer (score 4):

You could add a class to every occurence of numbers on your page, and simply change the `font-family` of said class.

**HTML**

```
<p> .... <span class="number">42</span> ... </p>
```

**CSS**

```
.number{
  font-family: 'myFont';
}
```

Comment: i want change font only 13

Comment: You can't have two fonts inside the same selector. You need to add a `span` (or anything else, really) around your numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class for all your number set like this:

```
//css
.number{ font-family: 'your-font-name', fallback-font; }

//html
<p>something <span class='number'>877866</span> goes here</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

in css :

```
input[type="number"] {
    font-family: 'customFont';
}
```

in html :

```
<input type="number" name="number">
```

Answer (score 0):

**NUMBERS TO MONOSPACE**

To anyone who is doing this just so he could have numbers as a monospace font, i would recommend doing this instead:

```
input{
font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums
}
```

[Here is more info about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric)